# Auto-send variable email based on cell change

Tags: sendmail

I've searched extensively through StackOverflow for a solution to this, and found three or four posts that came close to what I'm looking for. The code below seems to most closely achieve what I want to do, with one glitch: it only sends the data from the first row (regardless of which row the cell change occurs). I suspect the problem is in the structure of the getRange lines, but I don't know how to fix it.

Set-up: I have a Google Sheet open with column B populated with a drop-down menu of options. Column G has email addresses. The other columns contain data input via a Google Form.

Objective: When I change the value of the column B cell (Status), I want the script to automatically send an email to the address in column G (with the new value of column B and data from column I).

Current experience/problem: when I change the value in column B, in any row, an email is sent to the address in row 2 with that row's data, vs. the address from the row where I made the change.

Here's my code...

```
function SendNotification(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY UNIQUE SHEET ID");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var statusUpdate = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValue();
  var requestedItem = sheet.getRange("I2:I").getValue();
  //Range must start at G2, otherwise the header returns a non-valid email error.
  var emailToSend = sheet.getRange("G2:G").getValue();
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailToSend, "Status Update - Resource Request", "Your resource request for " + requestedItem+ " was just updated to: " + statusUpdate+ ".");
  }
}
```

I appreciate any assistance!